# I can't filter data when set state?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, filter

I have a two array **first one** contains all orders, second one that contains a rejected orders I got them from my Database

I need to filter these orders and remove all rejected orders from it based on snapshot key

so after running my code

I see all orders and contain the rejected although I test my code in the console and it works fine but in my React App not work

Orders Array

```
let ordersArray = [
   {"snapshotKey":"-awdawadsdwwd","username":"Joe"},
   {"snapshotKey":"-badsdasdad","username":"Annna"},
   {"snapshotKey":"-dasQwaddas","username":"lee"}
]

let rejectedOrders = ["-awdawadsdwwd","-dasQwaddas"] //these orders snapshot keys
```

just to make my code short I will put the pieces of filtering

after getting orders and push it to separate array I set the state like this

```
    this.setState({
      orders: orderArr.filter(
        order => !rejectedOrders.some(key => order.snapshotKey === key),
      ),
      loading: false,
    });
```

but sadly I got the three orders without any filtering!

**Edit 1**

```
Const {rejectedOrders}= this.state;
database()
      .ref(
        `Providers/CategoriesOrders/${service ||
          serviceStorage ||
          serviceName}/${uid}`,
      )
      .on('value', snapshot => {
        console.log(snapshot.val());
        let orderArr = [];
        snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
          orderArr.push({
            snapshotKey: childSnapshot.key,
            username: childSnapshot.val().username,
            buildingNumber: childSnapshot.val().buildingNumber,
            service: childSnapshot.val().categoryName,
            date: childSnapshot.val().date,
            time: childSnapshot.val().time,
            description: childSnapshot.val().problemDescription,
            status: childSnapshot.val().status,
            images: childSnapshot.val().Images,
          });
        });
        this.setState({
      orders: orderArr.filter(
        order => !rejectedOrders.some(key => order.snapshotKey === key),
      ),
      loading: false,
    });
      });
```

Comment: This should work, I think you're having an issue somewhere else.

Comment: @AkhilNayak Check the question again please

Comment: @goto1 Yeah i test it in the separate js file and works fine I don't know why not works here :/

Comment: @AkhilNayak I got all orders!

Comment: This should work fine, where are you seeing that it is not working?

Comment: @Auticcat  It's works if i use the prevState check my full code here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59355795/cant-update-state-immediately